# error overflow pasing value to smart contract method

Tags: solidity, nodejs, typescript

I am having an error when I want to send values ​​to the method in my smart contract, an example of what I am sending is:

```
{
  from: '0x285A3aF6cAF3483676Ef10416784636b109eE6a8',
  to: '0xDba8ce4f977467130C694100B44eD3C47E32c174',
  gas: '300000',
  value: '1000000000000000000',
  data: ''
}
```

bus the data i try to pass is array like

```
to  = [ '0x53393514FA67B3BcC06C3B5D0E10aA480630488d' ] 
values = [ 1000000000000000000 ]
```

and the error that returns me is

> (node:3944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: overflow
> (fault="overflow", operation="BigNumber.from",
> value=1000000000000000000, code=NUMERIC_FAULT,
> version=bignumber/5.5.0)

the method within the S.C is:

```
function batchTransferEth(
        address payable [] memory addresses,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256 gas,
        uint256 length
    ) external payable onlyAuthAccount nonReentrant {
        uint256 totalAmount = 0;
        require(addresses.length == length, "wrong number of addresses");
        require(amounts.length == length, "wrong number of amounts");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            totalAmount += amounts[i];
        }
        require(totalAmount == msg.value, "insufficient total value to send");
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            // invoque low level call through the Address library
            Address.sendValueGas(addresses[i], amounts[i], gas);
            // logs transaction in the blockchain
            emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, addresses[i], amounts[i]);
        }
    }
```

the error explodes when I try to pass create the encodeABI

```
tx.data =  contractBatch.methods.batchTransferEth(to, values, gasTotal, countTo).encodeABI()
```

gasTotal and countTo is a number normal

when i test from remix it works fine i am using ganache for local network

Comment: Try surrounding values with double quotes, like this `values = [ "1000000000000000000" ]`

Comment: Yes! it worked, it was just that, thank you